# How to reuse my xml relative layout in android

Tags: android

Hi I have an m file which is a relative layout and which contains 9 image buttons.
So I would like to reuse my layout multiple times just by changing the names and ID's.
I am able to do with gridview but my problem is I want use the same customs design which I have using relative layout. 
So can any one help how to do it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/day0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/day1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/day0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/day3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/day0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day0"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:src="@drawable/day3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/day6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/day3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day3"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:src="@drawable/day6" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/day4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/day6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/day3"
        android:src="@drawable/day4" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/day7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/day4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/day6"
        android:src="@drawable/day7" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/day1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/day4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/day1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/day8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/day5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/day7"
        android:src="@drawable/day8" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/day2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/day1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/day1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/day2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/day5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/day6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/day2"
        android:src="@drawable/day5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/day7"
        android:text="Emotions"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Ans6b"
        android:text="Leadership"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Ans6b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/question6a"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/question6a"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/day1"
        android:text="gruppstart"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/day4"
        android:text="Adaption"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day6"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/day4"
        android:text="Behavior"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day8"
        android:text="Satisfaction"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/day5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day5"
        android:text="Insight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/day2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day2"
        android:text="relationer"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question6a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Goal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my xml file I would like to call this xml file for different activities but just by changing the names ID and some display image buttons.
How to do that can any one please suggest me

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.xylem.flygt.R;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity 
{

    static GridView gridView;

    Bitmap bmp = null;
    public ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    Context context; 
    ImageButton day0, day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7, day8;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

        day0 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.day0);
        day1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.day1);       
        day2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.day2);
        day3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.day3);
        day4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.day4);
        day5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.day5);
        day6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.day6);
        day7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.day7);
        day8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.day8); 

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);  
        gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E3E4FA"));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                System.out.println("Clicked id " + position);

                if(position == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(" Day 0 ");


                }

                if(position == 1)               {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivity.class);         
                    i.putExtra("dayno", "1");
                    System.out.println(" Day 1 ");
                    startActivity(i);

                }

                if(position == 2)
                {   
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivity.class);         
                    i.putExtra("dayno", "2");
                    System.out.println(" Day 2 ");
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                if(position == 3)
                {   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivity.class);         
                    i.putExtra("dayno", "3");
                    System.out.println(" Day 3 ");  
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                if(position == 4)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivity.class);         
                    i.putExtra("dayno", "4");
                    System.out.println(" Day 4 ");          
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                if(position == 5)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivity.class);         
                    i.putExtra("dayno", "5");
                    System.out.println(" Day 5 ");               
                    startActivity(i);
                }       

                if(position == 6)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivity.class);         
                    i.putExtra("dayno", "6");
                    System.out.println(" Day 6");
                    startActivity(i);
                }   

                if(position == 7)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivity.class);         
                    i.putExtra("dayno", "7");
                    System.out.println(" Day 7 ");
                    startActivity(i);
                }   

                if(position == 8)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivity.class);         
                    i.putExtra("dayno", "8");
                    System.out.println(" Day 8 ");
                    startActivity(i);
                }             
            }
        });

        new Checkday().execute(); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class Checkday extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {   
                protected void onPreExecute() 
                {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
                {
                    return null;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
                {   
                            gridView.setAdapter(new CalenderAdaptor(MenuActivity.this));
                }
        }
    }
```

I have written  my activity java it itself creates the image buttons in a gridview. But I use like this I want to use in such way that I call my customs layout in different activities because the layout is same only the IDs and some images will change.

Comment: Show us your code and the error you are getting.

Comment: Why do you want to change the ids? What do you want to exactly achieve? What have you tried? Show us some code. We aren't writing code for you!

Comment: I want change IDs because I will using the same layout type for multiple activities. so thats why to change it but my problems the layout which is designed I was unable to reuse it as I want.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand it right - you have a custom design layout with buttons and you want to use this same layout in other screen as well.

You don't need to rename anything, just put the layout in a separate xml, let's say CommonButtonLayout.xml. This should contain like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

.... your layout .....

</merge>
```

Now you want to use this in other layout files. You need to include this xml directly there like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    ...
     >

    <include
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        layout="@layout/CommonButtonLayout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No I want to use my xml layout by changing ids in other activities.